# How to reconnect already paired bluetooth controller?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, game-controller

I cannot find any helpful information online, either they say "run Windows update" or "reinstall bluetooth drivers". The drivers are not a problem, Windows settings just does not have the option to connect to an already paired device. Is this a design flaw or am I missing something? Google is useless as can be and doesn't give anything that can give me an idea of how you're supposed to connect a game pad/controller that's already paired. I can of course unpair and pair again, but I have gotten sick of doing this every single time. On all other operating systems there is a simple button to connect the paired devices. How to do this on Windows??

Comment: Which controller? Windows does of course have the option to reconnect a paired device.

Comment: Windows auto-connects to paired devices on boot. Doesn't it happen for you?

Comment: I'm also curious if anyone has an answer for this. I have a bluetooth usb dongle in my pc, and my wireless earbuds never reconnect. I always have to "remove device" and then re-pair as a new device. Quite frustrating (Win10).

Comment: @harrymc It only automatically connects sometimes, and only if the device hasn't been connected with another device in the meantime. Maybe the connect functionality is enabled by a driver, for some wireless speakers it does work. On Windows 8 there is no option to connect at all. Very frustrating.

Comment: If the problem only arises after you've paired the device with another computer, then the problem is with the device itself. I t might not have a solution on the computer side.